# Order of reading Danganronpa manga and light novel?

Tags: danganronpa

I found a lot of danganronpa manga series and light novel. So what is the order of reading Danganronpa manga and LN?

Manga

1. Danganronpa: The Manga
2. Danganronpa: Trigger Happy Havoc 4koma KINGS The Manga
3. Danganronpa 2: Goodbye Despair: The Manga
4. Super Danganronpa 2: Sayonara Zetsubou Gakuen: 4-Koma KINGS The Manga
5. Super Danganronpa 2 - Komaeda Nagito no Kouun to Kibou to Zetsubou
6. Super Danganronpa 2 - Nankoku Zetsubou Carnival!: The Manga
7. Super Danganronpa 2: Nanami Chiaki no Sayonara Zetsubou Daibouken
8. Super Danganronpa 2: Sayonara Zetsubou Gakuen - Comic Anthology
9. Zettai Zetsubou Shoujo - Danganronpa Another Episode: The Manga
10. Zettai Zetsubō Shōjo: Danganronpa Another Episode - Genocider Mode: The Manga
11. Zettai Zetsubo Shojo Danganronpa Another Episode - Comic Anthology

Light Novel

1. Danganronpa/Zero
2. Danganronpa: Trigger Happy Havoc IF
3. Danganronpa: Togami
4. Danganronpa Kirigiri
5. Ultra Despair Hagakure
6. Danganronpa 1 ・2 Beautiful Days
7. Makoto Naegi's Worst Day Ever

Comment: Order of what exactly?

Comment: in terms of the manga Trigger Happy Havoc is the subtitle to the first Danganronpa game but the fact it's 4koma would make me think that they are side stories set during the first manga/game. Another Episode is apart of the full title of the third game *Danganronpa Another Episode: Ultra Despair Girls* which if i recall is set chronologically after the first game.....assuming that the Another Episode Manga you list are adaptations of Ultra Despair Girls. Goodbye Despair is the second game so i would assume it's an adaption of the second game as such it should come after Ultra Despair Girls

Comment: Zettai Zetsubou Shoujo also roughly [translates in google](https://translate.google.com.au/#ja/en/Zettai%20Zetsubou%20Shoujo) as Absolute Despair Girl so i wouldn't be surprised if the manga is an adaptation of Ultra Despair Girls, though i don't know why there is a Genocide Mod and Anthology Manga