# Where can I watch the rest of Danganronpa series after Danganronpa 1?

Tags: danganronpa, streaming-sites

I've just finished watching *Danganronpa 1*. Where can I watch the others?

I cannot use Funimation.

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! Please note that this site does not endorse piracy, so you'll only receive answers to legal streaming services.

Comment: Note that there is only an adaptation of *Danganronpa 1* and an original series *Danganronpa 3*. Related: [Order to watch the Danganronpa series? Is there a “Danganronpa 2”?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/34533/2516)

Comment: You can use XDCC on Rizon IRC to download it. Make sure that's legal where you live, though.

Answer (score 1):

Hulu and Crunchyroll may have it I'm not exactly sure now though
[1]: https://www.hulu.com/series/danganronpa-the-animation-cea65c1b-85df-43b2-bb88-341e0ec1074b

Comment: Note that the Hulu link is pointing to *Danganronpa 1*. Though, looks like Crunchyroll has [*Danganronpa 3*](https://www.crunchyroll.com/danganronpa-3-the-end-of-hopes-peak-high-school).